# WCF Service host in IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an WCF it is run Successfully when i run it my local host. But i face a problem when run it against a specific domain address(www.esimsol.com). Any one help me how can i config it for ("http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite/eval.svc"). My local host config file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="EvalServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior"
        name="EvalServiceLibrary.EvalService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="EvalServiceLibrary.IEvalService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/EvalServiceLibrary/EvalService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EvalServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Note : Specially base Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
   <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
   </identity>
```

&

```
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/EvalServiceLibrary/EvalService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to publish your solution to your iis server with name http://www.esimsol.com.
after publishing it try running your service with address:http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite/eval.svc
and change your base addresss to

you cannot use your loacalhost server 8081 after publishing it to any server either it should be localhost or your website name http://www.esimsol.com

Comment: replace base address with www.esimsol.com i host my service again in IIS. But when i try to invoke my service I get following message : There was no endpoint listening at http://win-ea8mlbabe9t/evalservicesite/eval.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: dude you have to host/publish this website in IIS with this name  http://www.esimsol.com.once it is published successfully then only this will be a valid address.

Comment: its publish successfully but i get same message

Comment: dude you have to provide your client endpoint also.i cannot find your client endpoint in above mentioned config.thats the main reason.